# Excel Group Text Box and Picture

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

I found some code to add an image to an Excel-sheet with the SDK 2.0. And this part works fine. Now I want a Text Box under the Image, but I don't know how to get a TextBox in general.

Which classes do I need an what is appands what or which property?

Furthermore it would be nice if it be groupt. So that when you drag one the other is following.

The code look like this (I know it's a bit much, but I couldt cut it more):

```
private void addImage(Offset offset, Extents extents, string sImagePath, string description)
    {
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = this.arbeitsBlatt.WorksheetPart;
        DrawingsPart drawingsPart;
        ImagePart imagePart;
        XDrSp.WorksheetDrawing worksheetDrawing;

        ImagePartType imagePartType = getImageType(sImagePath);

        {
            // --- use the existing DrawingPart
            drawingsPart = worksheetPart.DrawingsPart;
            imagePart = drawingsPart.AddImagePart(imagePartType);
            drawingsPart.CreateRelationshipToPart(imagePart);
            worksheetDrawing = drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing;
        }

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(sImagePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            imagePart.FeedData(fileStream);
        }

        int imageNumber = drawingsPart.ImageParts.Count<ImagePart>();
        if (imageNumber == 1)
        {
            Drawing drawing = new Drawing();
            drawing.Id = drawingsPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart);
            this.arbeitsBlatt.Append(drawing);
        }

        XDrSp.NonVisualDrawingProperties noVisualDrawingProps = new XDrSp.NonVisualDrawingProperties();
        XDrSp.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties noVisualPictureDrawingProps = new XDrSp.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties();

        noVisualDrawingProps.Id = new UInt32Value((uint)(1024 + imageNumber));
        noVisualDrawingProps.Name = "Picture " + imageNumber.ToString();
        noVisualDrawingProps.Description = beschreibung;

        PictureLocks picLocks = new PictureLocks();
        picLocks.NoChangeAspect = true;
        picLocks.NoChangeArrowheads = true;
        noVisualPictureDrawingProps.PictureLocks = picLocks;

        XDrSp.NonVisualPictureProperties noVisualPictureProps = new XDrSp.NonVisualPictureProperties();
        noVisualPictureProps.NonVisualDrawingProperties = noVisualDrawingProps;
        noVisualPictureProps.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties = noVisualPictureDrawingProps;

        Stretch stretch = new Stretch();
        stretch.FillRectangle = new FillRectangle();

        XDrSp.BlipFill blipFill = new XDrSp.BlipFill();
        Blip blip = new Blip();
        blip.Embed = drawingsPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart);
        blip.CompressionState = BlipCompressionValues.Print;
        blipFill.Blip = blip;
        blipFill.SourceRectangle = new SourceRectangle();
        blipFill.Append(stretch);

        Transform2D t2d = new Transform2D();
        t2d.Offset = offset;
        t2d.Extents = extents;
        XDrSp.ShapeProperties sp = new XDrSp.ShapeProperties();
        sp.BlackWhiteMode = BlackWhiteModeValues.Auto;
        sp.Transform2D = t2d;
        PresetGeometry prstGeom = new PresetGeometry();
        prstGeom.Preset = ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle;
        prstGeom.AdjustValueList = new AdjustValueList();
        sp.Append(prstGeom);
        sp.Append(new NoFill());

        XDrSp.Picture picture = new XDrSp.Picture();
        picture.NonVisualPictureProperties = noVisualPictureProps;
        picture.BlipFill = blipFill;
        picture.ShapeProperties = sp;

        XDrSp.OneCellAnchor anchor = this.getCellAnchor();

        XDrSp.Extent extent = new XDrSp.Extent();
        extent.Cx = extents.Cx;
        extent.Cy = extents.Cy;
        anchor.Extent = extent;

        anchor.Append(picture);
        anchor.Append(new XDrSp.ClientData());

        worksheetDrawing.Append(anchor);
        worksheetDrawing.Save(drawingsPart);

        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are new to OpenXml SDK

First of all you need to use the newest version of Open XMl SDK - Version 2.5  [Download - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425]

Here download BOTH OpenXMLSDKV25.msi , OpenXMLSDKToolV25.msi .. Install BOTH.

Now here is the trick, OpenXML productivity tool is the one you need here. It allows you to brows an existing Excel file and break it down to CODES [watch here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSSMLR19JWA]

Now what you need to do is create an Excel sheet manually with what you want [In your case add Text Box under the Image] Then open this Excel file with productivity tool and understand the CODE . Note that you will need to understand Spreadsheet file structure to understand this CODE [ Reffer this - https://www.google.com/#q=open+xml+sdk] .. Now write your codes to meet your requirement using codes of Productivity tool

NOTE - Once you analyse the dummy Spreadsheet with Productivity tool you will understand why giving or guiding with CODE examples as an answer is not practical.
- Happy Coding-

Comment: Yeah, ... I forgot this tool. Thanks for the links.